# the difference between a set and an ensemble

Tags: statistics, cryptography

I am reading a paper in cryptography, there is something that I cannot understand well! here is the paragraph:

> An inherently unobfuscatable function ensemble is an ensemble
> $\{H_k\}_{k∈N}$ of distributions $H_k$ on finite functions (from, say,
> $\{0, 1\}^{l_{in(k)}}$ to $\{0, 1\}^{l_{out(k)}}$) such that:
>
> 1. Every function $f\xleftarrow{R}H_k$ is computable by a circuit of size poly(k)....

I could not understand the concept of ensembles and their difference with sets. It seams that an ensemble is a set with some parameter like k. For example here I see the ensemble $\{H_k\}_{k∈N}$ as a set $\{H_1, H_2, ...\}$. Am I right? If yes then why we need the concept of ensembles?

The other question is that what does the notation $f\xleftarrow{R}H_k$ implies for? Is it randomly sampling one element from the ensemble (set)?

I feel that I really need a concrete example to get the different between a set and ensemble. Let say there are some objects. If I put them in an ensemble what would I get more in compare to put them in a set?

Comment: "Ensemble" is the French word for "set". I suppose nothing deep is being meant or implicated here, it just means a set. Some people prefer to call sets ensembles, and it is not odd usage because "ensemble" is an English word as well at the end of the day (not exactly sure though how it is usually understood, but it carries among its meanings the notion of "set")